# VSC showing problems despite having no code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've done a bit of coding before with C#, since I use it to make my own code while learning in CodeAcademy.

However, it kept showing problems despite having the variables cleared. I tried deleting all code. However, the problems persisted, saying the variables does not exist, when they already do not exist in the first place because I cleared them after use.

Did I press anything that caused this?
Edit: Forgot to say this, but I'm in version 1.54.3.

No code, yet there are 11 problems. What's going on?

[image]

Comment: I've never used VS Code for C#, but visual studio behaves the same way. Either try rebuilding, or deleting the `bin` and `obj` directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use "dotnet restore" command in the terminal.

Comment: That works, thanks man! I have no idea why this happens but thanks for the help.